# Limit entry in column in Table in Excel (2010, ...) to unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a Table in Excel for data entry and in this table I have a column `mod_key`in which **only unique values** should be allowed.

I know about the data validation and I have tried the following based on [the link here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal07.html)

```
=COUNTIF(mod_key,B6) <= 1
```

but I get the error message "The formula you typed contains an error"

I tried it in Excel 2011 and 2016 on Mac and it doesn't work on either.

Any ideas what is wrong with this formula?

---

### EDIT 1

I have created a table as follow:

[image: Screenshot]

I uploaded the basic .xlsx to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8275uwzx0rm9lyu/unique_id.xlsx?dl=0).

Now I would like to have the unique value in column id. The formula I an using =now is :

```
= =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Table1[id]");A4) <= 1
```

I have read somewhere that INDIRECT should be avoided - but how can I?

---

Comment: Have you tried replace comma `,` with semi-column `;`?

Comment: Also `COUNTIF` as all functions is localized: in Spanish `CONTAR.SI` in French `NB.SI`...

Comment: Thanks - that is working. But I can't enter any values now as it is alwas categorized as "duplicate".

Comment: @Djee So will my spreadsheet work with other localized versions of MS?

Comment: Yes, from my experience you cannot enter a function in another language what anyhow does not prevent your Excel workbook to be portable. Could you detect duplicate values properly now? If not I suggest to use cells new to your column with `COUNTIF(...)` as formula and figure out what's going on (`COUNTIF` gives you how many times value as second parameter is met in range as first parameter)

Comment: Well - sort off - see my comments in my question.

Comment: Seems `INDIRECT` is not needed. See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems there is something weird with **validation** in Excel: it does not accept named column. I succeeded with an absolute range however. Example:

```
=COUNTIF($A$4:$A$1000;A4) <= 1
```

Comment: That would work, but it defies the purpose of tables.

Comment: What is it you call `table`? I only know ranges, name of ranges, cells...

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-Excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c for Tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me in Excel 2010:

1. Select whole table column
2. Go to Data tab, Data Validation, Settings tab
3. In Allow box choose Custom
4. In Formula box enter: `=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("TableName[ColumnName]"),INDIRECT("TableName[@ColumnName]"))<2`
5. Press OK

In general, for data validation, using the INDIRECT("") way of referring to the names found in tables appears to work.

Kind regards. Mouse.